# How can I set the initial controller on storyboard contains WKInterfaceController programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode6, watchkit

I want to have few view controllers on the Watch app storyboard. The issue is that I want to load different initial view controller depending the target I'm building for.

I can see there is a single value called "is initial controller" on the WKInterfaceController but I can't find a way to set the initial view programmatically. I tried using other methods supplied but all are pushing the second view on top of the original initial which is not what I want (you have a back button on top bar).

If you have any way you can think of supporting this that's great. Creating a different storyboard file is last option.

Comment: The initial view controller flag is just an entry in the storyboard file. You cannot set it at runtime.

Comment: @Paulw11 I understand that, But is there any way to set the initial WKViewController ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the solution is really simple. It is true that the pages are being built before everything I had to rebuild all of it at run time. More that the flag (Is initial Controller) couldn't be changed at run time but you sure can build all from scratch.

I set the identifier of the WKViewController to "exampleViewControllerName" (on the StoryBoard) and add this code to awakeWithContext:context

```
NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"exampleViewControllerName", nil];
[WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:array1 contexts:nil];
```

You sure can use the context and make that more complicated but that's the basic of it, and good enough for the simplest answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually asking is how can you control the initial view controller of a watch kit app.

From the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html)

> All interface controllers in a page-based interface are created and
> initialized before the interface is displayed, but only one interface
> controller at a time is displayed. Normally, WatchKit displays the
> first interface controller in the sequence initially. To change the
> initially displayed interface controller, call the `becomeCurrentPage`
> method from its `init` or `awakeWithContext:` method.

If you are using a hierarchical interface rather than a page-based interface then your app will always start with the same initial view.